# Algebraic Operations with Summation within summation

Tags: statistics, summation

Given $x_i = (X_i - \bar{X})$, where $\bar{X}$ is the sample mean of $X$; and given the variable $k_i = \frac{x_i}{\sum x_i^2}$.

How do I show that $\sum k_i x_i = \sum k_i X_i = 1$?

I don't know how to incorporate information about the sample mean. Perhaps this has some statistics knowledge that I don't know? I don't know how to deal with a summation within a summation that all uses i.

Comment: You should rename the parameter in the summation, such that $$k_i=\frac{x_i}{\sum x_j^2}$$
Finally note that, since this is just a notation,  $$\sum x_i^2=\sum x_j^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X:=[X_1,\ldots,X_n]^{\top}$ and $P:=\mathbf{i}\mathbf{i}^{\top}/n$, where $\mathbf{i}:=[1,\ldots, 1]^{\top}$. Note that the matrix $I-P$ is symmetric and idempotent, i.e., $I-P=(I-P)^{\top}$ and $(I-P)(I-P)=I-P$. Therefore,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n k_iX_i=\frac{X^{\top}(I-P)X}{((I-P)X)^{\top}(I-P)X}=\frac{X^{\top}(I-P)X}{X^{\top}(I-P)X}=1.
$$